# Which pop up modal can be used in the app in which ui-router has been used

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I have created a webpage in which different pages are opened through the Use of the UI-router different states for the each page opened and each page have may modules which are integrated through ng-include, Now I have the requirement of the popup modal needs to be integrated in my webpage but the pop modal doesnt work as expected Is their any popup modal which I can used in my webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [ngDialog](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/) and ui router. Here you can read:

> Modals and popups provider for Angular.js applications. No
>   dependencies. Highly customizable.

Works like a charm.

On the [documentation page](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scope-object) you can see how to pass the scope or any other information you will need into the scope of the dialog to create the logic you need in your modal dialog. Taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scope-object):

```
$scope.value = true;

ngDialog.open({
    template: 'externalTemplate.html',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain',
    scope: $scope
});
```

With a controller:

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'externalTemplate.html',
    scope: $scope
    controller: ['$scope', 'otherService', function($scope, otherService) {
        // controller logic
    }]
});
```

In your scenario it is perhaps possible to use an ng-click on your link. Do some logic in the ng-click function and then open the ngDialog in this function with the appropriate data. Does that make sense? Or is it perhaps better to first open the dialog and use the passed data to do the needed data loading in the dialog itself. Perhaps a better user experience! ;)

Comment: How did you get the data  which is dynamic and is changing according to the button on click

Comment: Hi Harish, I just edited my answer to show how to pass scope information into the dialog scope. Does that help. But I am afraid I did not understand your scenario fully. Can you explain it a little bit more, if my edit does not help you.

Comment: thanks, @timtos It worked and now I am able to tranfer the value without any issue but their is small problem   I was using the controller as syntax using "this" , I tried the same but Seems I can use only $scope since it didnt consider the scope:this approach but nevertheless Your  answer did solve my problem but if you by any chance know how to use it in controller as syntax that will be good thank since you already solved the isssue

Comment: Hi Harish, I don't use this syntax but I found this here in the documentation: "You could optionally specify  controllerAs  parameter for your controller. Then inside your template it will be possible to refer this controller by value specified by  controllerAs ." Have a look here: https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#controlleras-string Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the Angular Modal service to create a modal.
Please refer to the below link.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I have checked but my requirement state that I had to Get the data also according to the item on which it is clicked, that means that I have create a get request according to the click for the data , I have seen through ngDialog module but no reference is their